# Python readline from different line of growing text file Incrementally

Tags: python

I have a growing text file and want to read from different line everytime the text file has new line added from line 1500 so when the program hits 1501 i want to start reading from line 2 1502 line 3 so the list is always 1500 lines long and doesnt go over I think the way I have done it is very bad but im not an expert

```
TEXT_FILE.write(strdata) # writing to file

with open('output.txt') as file:

    lineslen = len(file.readlines())  # get line numbers in file
    linesstring = file.readlines()  # read all lines

    if lineslen < 1500:
        fileline = open('output.txt', 'rb')
        filelines = fileline.readlines()

        self.ids.special_gridlayout.ids.special_label.text = \
            str(filelines)

    if lineslen > 1500:

        file1 = open('output.txt', 'rb')

        lineint = int(lineslen / 1.5)  # not sure what operator to use

                            # with open("num_file.json", "w") as handle:
                            # json.dump(lines, handle)
                            # linenumber = json.load(handle)

        linesstring2 = file1.readlines()[lineint:]  # this need to start from the integer in
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. Also - what's your question?

Comment: sorry hope its more clear now

Comment: you need to use `file.seek("your_postion)´ and `file.tell()` to start reading from your last line and go on from there

Comment: Heavily depends on your data? I think @LinPy points towards the right direction, especially if line size in bytes is constant. Otherwise concurrently load chunks from the file and 'grow' each line.